# how to resolve xss vulnerability for javascript code

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, jscript

I am getting the below response post the security scan done on website and tool says the following:

Method lambda() sends unvalidated data to a web browser on line below: 
I am confused how can this be managed.

```
.html("$ " + formatMoney($("#financial_sales_price").val() - total_subtotals_val));
```

Can somebody assist to resolve this vulnerability.

Comment: Unless there are actually HTML elements in the string you're appending, use `text()` instead

Comment: not much clear could you please be more clear @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: take a look at code i placed below

Comment: @lancer change `.html` to `.text`

Answer (score 0):

you should use `.text()` instead `.html()`.

it's slower, but safer - any possible html data will be displayed as entifies, not fired as html. see example here:

```js
  $(function(){
      $("#div1").html('<a href="example.html">Link</a><b>hello</b>');
      $("#div2").text('<a href="example.html">Link</a><b>hello</b>');
        
      $("#div3").html('&lt;a href="example.html"&gt;Link&lt;/a&gt;');
      $("#div4").text('&lt;a href="example.html"&gt;Link&lt;/a&gt;');
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<hr/>
<div id="div3"></div>
<div id="div4"></div>
<div id="work"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1.parse to Number

```
        .html("$ " + 
    formatMoney(
    parseFloat($("#financial_sales_price").val())
     - parseFloat(total_subtotals_val)
));
```

2.use xss-filters module

https://www.npmjs.com/package/xss-filters